# Detect when image has finished rendering on screen

Tags: angularjs, image, rendering

This is essentially my HTML. It is part of a responsive design so I cannot rely on fixed widths/heights:

```
<img ng-src="{{imageSrc}}" />
```

The value of `$scope.imageSrc` is changed inside my controller and the view is updating properly.

But: At the point of time the image has finished rendering I need to get its `clientWidth` and `clientHeight` properties.

So how can I detect programmatically that

1. the image has finished loading and
2. the view has been fully updated with the rendered image

without using weird timeouts?

Comment: I think $timeout(, 0) in onload should do the trick for 2.

Comment: It works but it seems weird to use this type of "timeout hack"

Comment: I am not condering this a hack. Javascript is one thread, so using timeout with 0 is absolutely ok, behavior of such code is quite stable. Well, at least I think so.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two other questions will help you here.
This [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17884399/image-loaded-event-in-for-ng-src-in-angularjs) will detect loading via the `load` event.
And [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14578356/how-to-detect-when-an-image-has-finished-rendering-in-the-browser-i-e-painted) will detect rendering via `requestAnimationFrame`.

Comment: I will check this out

Comment: Yes that does the trick ... I can even get the rendered image's width/height within the first requestAnimationFrame callback